Are there any problems with this notation?
I have been regularly using this notation in my notes to denote multiple integrals by placing many integral signs in brackets:
$$\left(\int_{C_1} +\int_{C_2}+\int_{C_3}\right) f(\xi) d\xi \overset{def}{=} \int_{C_1} f(\xi) d\xi+\int_{C_2}f(\xi) d\xi+\int_{C_3}f(\xi) d\xi.$$
I have seen a few lecturers do it on the blackboard, but have no examples of typeset texts where this is used. I am writing up a handin at the moment, and I wondered if it would be inappropriate to use it. As I see it, the notation is pretty intuitive, and causes no possibilitites for ambiguity. Am I wrong? Should I be careful using this?

If you've never seen that in typeset sources, you might just not have read enough discussions of contour integration.

Some texts do it. Remember - so long as you define the notation and make sure it's unambiguous, you can use it.

Why would you do this?  To save time (writing on a blackboard, or taking live notes).  In your handin do you need to save time for some reason?

@GEdgar - It saves the reader from having to inspect the integrand three times. Not a huge savings, admittedly, but it makes it very easy for me to see it as "integrate this over three curves, and add 'em up". I might be over-influenced by years of programming, where factoring out common code is the rule.

In functional analysis and related fields, integration and differentiation are understood as linear operators which act on spaces of functions.  So, for example, one might define an operator
$$ D : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) : f \mapsto f'. $$
That is, the differential operator $D$ is a function with domain and codomain $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of smooth functions in a single real variable) which takes a function and outputs it's derivative.  Similarly, one might define
$$ \int : L^1(\mathbb{R}) \to L^1(\mathbb{R}) : f \mapsto \int f, $$
or
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} : L^1(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R} : f \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} f.$$
In the first case, the operator gives an indefinite integral of $f$ (there is some ambiguity which needs to be resolved, related to constants of integration), and in the second example the operator is a special kind of linear operator, called a linear functional, which outputs a real number.  Linear operators are a kind of function, so it is not entirely unreasonable to ask what kind of algebraic structure can be defined using them, e.g. they can be composed in the "obvious" manner and, if you do some work with the spectral theorem and the functional calculus, it is possible to describe the addition and multiplication of such operators.
Moreover, if the $C_i$ are curves and the integration suggested is a contour integral (as appears to be the case), then it is also possible to reason that
$$ \int_{C_1 \cup C_2} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{C_1} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{C_2} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$
(Note that the curves may not be disjoint, but if they intersect at only a finite number of points, there is no real problem.  In particular, a curve $C$ may be partitioned into several pieces, say $C_1$ through $C_n$, and the integral taken over the pieces.)  In such a case, it is not unreasonable to use the shorthand notation suggested in the question.
TL;DR: The notation suggested in the question is probably quite fine, particularly if it is defined properly in the text.
